Parallel predictions on the same Keras Model
I have a .keras file (which I will use to load my model) and a huge dataset X (~5m rows) which I want to call model.predict(X) on to retrieve my predictions.
Is there any way to utilise multiprocessing/threading in order to speed this up? I was thinking of splitting up X in to different chunks and calling model.predict() on these subsets (in parallel). Python's multiprocessing requires the object to be pickled though, so I can't pass a keras.Model as an argument, meaning I'd have to load a fresh model for each thread/worker/instance, which is quite slow.
What's the general strategy for this?

This is literally what the batch size is for, no need to do it manually, just increase the batch size.
